# TCPDF, using $pdf->SetFont('msmincho', '', 7); increases file size

Tags: php, fonts, symfony1, tcpdf

```
<?php
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

    ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');

    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    $pdf->SetAuthor('Fxtrade');
    $pdf->SetTitle('AutoFX User Details');
    $pdf->SetSubject('AutoFX User Details');
    $pdf->SetFont('msmincho', '', 7);
    $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
    $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
    $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
    $pdf->SetMargins(12, 12, 12);
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
    $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
    $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
    $pdf->AddPage();

    $pdf->SetFillColor(100, 100, 100);

?>
```

I have very less content displayed in .pdf file, But the file size seems to be 2.9MB

I feel, some thing is wrong in font size,

please help me in reducing the file size

Comment: What's the file size with any other font/font size?

Comment: Clarify, Is the problem: 1) The text looks bigger or 2) The file size in bytes is bigger?

Comment: My thoughts are that the font is just a bigger size on disk and there is little you will be able to do about it

Comment: It seems it's just embedding that font into a pdf file

Comment: Thanks for every one, for your valuable comments, but with other fonts also i am getting the same size 2.9 MB. Is there any way i can reduce the file size.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the complete font is being embedded in the PDF when you use it.

A number of fonts can be used [without having to specifically embed them](http://www.tcpdf.org/fonts.php) in the PDF:

- courier : Courier
- courierB : Courier Bold
- courierBI : Courier Bold Italic
- courierI : Courier Italic
- helvetica : Helvetica
- helveticaB : Helvetica Bold
- helveticaBI : Helvetica Bold Italic
- helveticaI : Helvetica Italic
- symbol : Symbol
- times : Times New Roman
- timesB : Times New Roman Bold
- timesBI : Times New Roman Bold Italic
- timesI : Times New Roman Italic
- zapfdingbats : Zapf Dingbats

You can embed only the characters that have been used, which should reduce the size of the PDF, by passing `true` as the fifth parameter of [`setFont`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#afd56e360c43553830d543323e81bc045).

I don't know how much of a difference it will make but it should help a bit.